# NP-completeness of SHIP LOADING

Tags: np-complete

I need some help with the following question.

> SHIP LOADING: Given items of weights $x_1,\dots,x_n$, ships of weight
> capacity $B$, can the items be loaded onto $C$ or fewer ships? (All
> numbers are positive integers, given in binary.)
>
> Show that SHIP LOADING is NP-complete. (Hint: reduce from SUBSET SUM,
> but go through a restricted version where the target $b$ is half the
> total.)

My questions are:

> 1. Do you have any idea or hint about how to approach to prove that
>    this problem is a NP problem?
> 2. What does it mean by the target $b$ is half the total. Then, is the
>    sum of the indices $a_1,\dots,a_n$ equal to $b/2$?

Comment: For point 2 in your question, it would mean that you can load all items into one ship. Thats obviously not what you want.

Comment: Why does point 2 mean that all items can be loaded into one ship?

Comment: All items weights is only half of one ship's capacity...

Comment: So, does the total in the hint refer to one ship's capacity?

Comment: The SUBSET SUM variant is known as PARTITION. You are trying to partition the elements into two lists of equal sum. So if the target is $b$, then the elements sum to $2b$.

Comment: @nirshahar is mistaken, $B$ and $b$ are separate things. You are given $b$ as part of the Partition instance; you can decide what $B$ should be in the instance of Ship Loading that you are constructing from it. (You might decide to set $B=b$, but that's up to you.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker can I just set B as the average of all the given items of weights? And, don't I need to consider other cases that B is a positive number other than the average above?

Comment: You need to come up with a way to construct an entire instance of Ship Loading (including a value of $B$, a list of ship weights $x_1, \dots, x_n$ for some $n$, and a capacity $C$) from any given instance of Partition, in such a way that the instance of SL you construct has the answer YES if and only if the instance of Partition has the answer YES.

Comment: So, you mean that I can suppose B as a certain value, right? It seems like there is a way to construct an instance of SHIP LOADING as you described if I set B as the average of all items.

Comment: I think $B$ is not meant to be the average of all items, but something else. For PARTITION, we are trying to break elements up into two groups of equal size. If we want to reduce PARTITION to SHIP LOADING, how many ships do you think we should use to represent the partition? Once you settle on the value of $C$, the capacity of the ships $B$ will follow.

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied/quoted material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing